# how to get the reference number for a string input?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm setting up a Google form to get responses into Gsheets.
In Sheet 1, there will be an answer string such as "Theme Main" or "Theme Shop".
In Sheet 2, there will be a reference table, the first column is "Theme name", such as "Theme Main" or "Theme Shop" and more up to 50 rows. Then the 2nd column is "Theme#" from 1 to 50.

What I want is, for the answer string in Sheet 1, it will refer to Sheet 2 and return the Theme# in int32.

I had tried with `MATCH`, `VLOOKUP`...but seems is not what I need.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!E:F, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: although I still need to spend some time to learn the whole formula in detail, but it does the job already, thanks!

Comment: It's kind of strange, the formula does the job, but when a new row created automatically from Google form, the pre-copied formula will disappeared, yet the other rows still have the pre-copied formula.  If Google form will insert a new row, how can I have the pre-copied formula for that row?

Comment: yes, forms insert its own rows therefore if you want to have "pre-populated" rows you need to use ARRAYFORMULAs. for the formula from the answer it would be: `={"header"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!E:F, 2, 0)))}` - this way you can put it in 1st row and new form entries will not shift it downwards

Comment: what does the "header" mean? since I already have 14 rows in this sheet, should I create a clean new sheet to get the new form entries to be put in the 1st row? (it's OK if I should do so)

Comment: Worked it out, (although still not quite understand the formula), but it really does the job. Thanks!

Comment: you are creating an artificial array. paste this in some cell to see whats up: `={1;2}` now the formula from answer is kinda same but instead of `2` there is full arrayformula and instead of `1` you can put any text you wish (`"header"`,`"title"`, etc. ) or no text like: `={""; ARRAYFO.....`